# Rescaling x axis without altering y axis

Tags: plotting

I have a plot as follows:

```
Plot[{Sin[t]^2}, {t, 0, 3000}, Background -> White]

Plot[{Sin[t]^2}, {t, 0, 3000}, Background -> White, 
 Ticks -> {{#, 1/902*\[Pi]/4 #} & /@ FindDivisions[{0., 3000}, 6] // 
    N, Automatic}]
```

But I need to reexpress the plot in terms of `pi/4`, `pi/2`, `pi`. How to do this without altering y-axis?

Comment: tmax is undefined in your  code

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 1):

I think that the range of values of the x-axis is too large compared to how small the step of the ticks you want is. I am mentioning this since I have not been able to produce a nice plot.

Some toy-examples (with comparable ranges) follow:

The most straightforward way is:

```
Plot[Sin[t]^2, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/4], Automatic}]
```

Another way is shown below:

```
ticks = Union @@ Table[Range[0, 2 Pi, dt], {dt, {Pi/4, Pi/4}}];
Plot[{Sin[t]^2}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Ticks -> {ticks, Automatic}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Both of the above produce

[image]

For your values, it would be something like

```
ticks = Union @@ Table[Range[0, 955 Pi, dt], {dt, {Pi/4, Pi/4}}];

Plot[{Sin[t]^2}, {t, 0, 955 Pi}, Ticks -> {ticks, Automatic}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

but the ticks are not visible at all.

Hopefully, using the above you can either manipulate the plot-range, or the width of the ticks for your plots, or perhaps keep everything as it is.

Comment: That's the reason why I have converted the x axis to 1/902*\[Pi]/4 without altering y axis. After this first rescaling I asked for the pi/4 gapping rescale